# How do I remove certain items from the dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to filter responses from server that i store in dictionary.
Dictionary contains lists. I want to delete every list in each key where list doesn't contain 5 items.

I tried code like this

```py
def mutate_res(dic):
    for key in dic.keys():
        for response in dic[key]:
            if len(response) != 5:
                dic[key].remove(response)
    return dic
```

I expect dic[value] have only lists that contain 5 items but it's not working, it may have 3 or 5 items

Comment: Do **NOT** change a mutable object you iterate over.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse but what should i do instead? I don't want to create another instance of dictionary

Comment: Store the keys you want to remove and remove them after you iterate through the dict.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse i'll try to

Comment: Do you really need to mutate the passed in dictionary or just return one with the correct values?

Comment: @MarkMeyeri need to return dic with correct values

Comment: you change the parameter AND return it? that sounds really strange and your caller may not appreciate it

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre well... Now i undestand one more concept of programming. Thank you)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the keys to delete and delete them:

```
def mutate_res(dic):
    delete_me = [ k for k in dic if len(dic[k])!=5]
    for k in delete_me:
        del dic[k] 
    return dic
```

This does not delete anything while iterating so it is safe to do so.

---

Misread your data-structure - to remove inner lists of lenght != 5 you can do:

```
def mutate_res(dct):
    delete_me = [ k for k in dct if any(len(inner)!=5 for inner in dct[k])]
    for k in delete_me:
        dct[k] = [inner for inner in dct[k] if len(inner) == 5]
    return dct

d = {1: [ [1,],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5]]}

print(mutate_res(d)) # {1: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]}
```

Comment: Was the choice of `k` as the list comprehension variable a happy accident that it spells other words when accessing values in `dic`?

Comment: @Sayse `k` for `key` ? -but i renamed the `dic`;o)

Comment: I would not see it that way. k is the key. I think Sayse sees `dic[k]` as ... something offensive, which is far-fetched if you ask me

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - Not offensive, just slightly amusing when you're checking for its length

Comment: ROFL  didnt see that coming

Comment: well i didn't think of that. I'm just too lazy to type dictionary and key all the time so it happens...

Comment: restored the fun ;o)

Comment: I use `dct` personally :) also this is questionable to modify parameter _and_ return it. I know that's from OP interface but still...

Comment: @PatrickArtner somehow delete_me is always empty. I'll try to explain once again.
I have a dictionary of lists. And i want to delete every list in this dictionary that length is not 5 items

Comment: @jub You have lists of lists as data - not simple lists. See 2nd attempt :o)

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't need to mutate the dictionary in place, you can just use a comprehension and return the correct dictionary. Although I would consider changing the name of the function in that case so it's not misleading.

```
def mutate_res(dic):
    return {k:v for k,v in dic.items() if len(v) == 5}

d = {
    'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'b': [1,2],
    'c': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'd': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
mutate_res(d)
>> {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'd': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your code to use a list comprehension that filters out the unwanted elements:

```
def mutate_res(dic):
    for key in dic.keys():
        dic[key] = [x for x in dic[key] if len(x) != 5]
```